# TestNg reporter information repeated in surefire test results output

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

I've got a suite of selenium tests that are put together using TestNg and running on Jenkins using Maven and Surefire.

I'm trying to put together a test report to include custom information using the TestNg reporter info but am running into a problem with the surefire report repeating whatever I output using Reporter.log().

If I run the reports using the TestNg Eclipse plugin I get the following output under reporter output (in the TestNg test output):

Custom output goes here

If I run using surefire (mvn clean test) I get the following (in the Surefire test output):

Custom output goes here

Custom output goes here

Custom output goes here

Custom output goes here

Here's my failure override which creates the output:

```
public class TestListeners extends TestListenerAdapter{

    @Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult tr)
    {
        Reporter.log("Custom output goes here");
    }

}
```

The test:

```
public class ReportTest extends TestBase{

    @Test(groups="report")
    public void reportTest()
    {
        driver.navigate().to("https://www.google.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("no-element-here"));
    }
}
```

And the TestBase (used for setting up and tearing down the driver and environment):

```
@Listeners({TestListeners.class})
```

public class TestBase {

```
private Configuration config = new Configuration();
protected String base_url;
public static WebDriver driver;

@BeforeClass(alwaysRun=true)
public void setUp()
{
    driver = selectDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(config.timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    if(config.maximise)
    {
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }
    base_url = config.base_url;
}

@AfterClass(alwaysRun=true)
public void tearDown()
{
    driver.quit();
}
```

Also the pom, just in case:

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.18</version>
        <configuration>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.44.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I just can't figure out why it works fine when running in TestNg but randomly duplicates when running through Surefire. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked out what was happening here in case anyone stumbles across this in future.

It looks like every time there was a failure, and the override was called, it was called for every instance that existed. For example if the  @Listeners tag existed in 3 classes, the output would be repeated three times.

I resolved this by removed all @Listener tags that were present in Classes and added the following to my pom.xml nested within the SureFire plugin:

```
<properties>
    <property>
        <name>listener</name>
        <value>utilities.TestOverride</value>
    </property>
</properties>
```

All custom output is now displayed only once.